# Displaying from std::vector and handling events using SDL?

Tags: c++, vector, sdl

I am trying to make a custom app library with `SDL` as apart of an *academic project*, and I ran into an issue..

Basically, everything works fine, it compiles, does what I expect it to do, but... its extremely slow, the first element is reacting quite quickly, other elements within the set are completely unresponsive (i need to click them 20 times for the to react, they work just slow)

Below the function that draws the elements from a vector type container, the return 1 means that the handle function ran into an unexpected error or the user X'ed out the window.

Any advice on how to make this react faster?

```
void StoreDraw::setCamera(size_t input)
{
    rectangle.x = containerArray[input].elementLocX;
    rectangle.y = containerArray[input].elementLocY;
    rectangle.h = containerArray[input].elementPicture->h;
    rectangle.w = containerArray[input].elementPicture->w;
}

bool StoreDraw::vectorDraw()
{
    /* Draw FloatingElements */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < containerArray.size(); i++)
    {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))//containerArray[i].event
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                 if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                 {
                    locationX = event.button.x;
                    locationY = event.button.y;
                    printf("X:%d\tY:%d\n", locationX, locationY);
                    if(!containerArray[i].handleEvent(locationX, locationY)){drawEnvironment();}
                }
            }
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        } 
    }
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    return 0;
}

bool StoreDraw::drawEnvironment()
{
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0,0,0));
    SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, screen, NULL);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < containerArray.size(); i++)
    {
        setCamera(i);
        SDL_BlitSurface(containerArray[i].elementPicture, NULL, screen, &rectangle);
    }

    SDL_Flip(screen);
}

bool FloatingElement::handleEvent(int x, int y)
{
    printf("Object responding.\n");
    if((x > elementLocX) && (x < (elementLocX + (elementPicture->w))) && (y > elementLocY) && (y < (elementLocY + (elementPicture->h))))
    {
        x = (x - (elementPicture->w)/2);
        y = (y - (elementPicture->h)/2);
        setLocation(x,y);
        printf("Object responding.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Can you put more detail in it? Also I'd suggest using SDL2, it is a lot faster.

Comment: You are returning as soon as you get an event.  How about keeping track of the loop counter and continuing from where you left off instead of starting at 0 every time.

Comment: As explained the return 1 means that the handle function ran into an unexpected error or the user X'ed out the window, and only in that situation will the loop end prematurely (closing down the whole application). Debugged that loop and it works as intended, however still the second element, third element etc is unresponsive, only the first element is responding instantly.

Comment: I rewritten some code and optimized it at points, now the handling takes place in the storedraw class, and objects just retrieve the signals and act accordingly, but i have exacly the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the problem is how frequently you are checking for events. When you call vectorDraw() it polls the events and acts as intended, but the events eventually end and the function returns. I think there should be a main loop in the code that always checks for events and calls functions when necessary, while vectorDraw() only checks the location of a click and calls the handleEvent() of the container array.

Edit:
I think I found the problem. This is how you're doing now:

```
bool StoreDraw::vectorDraw()
{
    /* Draw FloatingElements */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < containerArray.size(); i++)
    {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))//containerArray[i].event
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                 if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                 {
                    // Check Events
                 }
            }
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        } 
    }
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
     while( ::quit == false ) {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) {
                if( event.type != SDL_QUIT ) {
                if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
                storeDraw::vectorDraw();
                }
                } else {
                quit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is happening:
After the main loop polls the event, it calls vectorDraw() and vectorDraw() polls events again. By doing so, vectorDraw() doesn't get the information of the click it called, as it was already polled in the main loop. Without the information, it doesn't act upon it.
So, in order to solve the problem, you can change the functions to be somewhat like this:

```
bool StoreDraw::vectorDraw(SDL_Event event)
{
    /* Draw FloatingElements */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < containerArray.size(); i++)
    {
        // Check Events
    }
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
     while( ::quit == false ) {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) {
                if( event.type != SDL_QUIT ) {
                if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
                        if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                        {
                    storeDraw::vectorDraw(event);
                        }
                }
                } else {
                quit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, only the main loop polls events and acts on them if possible. And vectorDraw() doesn't poll them anymore, only acts upon them if they meet it's criteria (left mouse button down, in this case). Now the event checking should act as intended.

Comment: My bad, I havent stated it clearly, there is a main loop in the main function. I thought its self explanatory. I first create the objects in the main class, then add them up to the vector and then start a loop that goes for just long until the user X out the window. The main function after a brief preparation process (configuring sdl etc) will then continuesly run the vectorDraw function.

Comment: So, I saw your comment and did some tests with a code fairly similar to yours and found your problem: after you click, the main loop calls vectorDraw() so that it may get the location of your click and act accordingly, but the click event was already polled, so vectorDraw() can't poll it again and will only act in the clicks that follow quickly after. In order to fix the problem, instead of making vectorDraw() poll events, you should give it the event that contained the click information. I'll edit the answer to clarify it.

Comment: It was defined like this before which did not resolve it. >.>

Comment: Try it. Instead of making vectorDraw() poll events, make it only receive events (as an argument) and check them. Leave event polling to the main loop only.

Comment: I didnt understand what you said in the first place but now i do when i see the code. and NO thats definitely not the case, since who would call the poll function 2 times in the first place? god no, how could you even this of that kind of stuff?